# How to emit values when a button is being pressed?

Tags: rxjs

I have a button — `<button></button>`.

This button is supposed to increment the value of an input field each time it is pressed. That's easy. The thing that I don't know  is how  to periodically increment the value while a button is being pressed and stop when user leaves the button or unpresses it. Here are the observables of all involded events. I need to combine them somehow to achieve the desired result. Any help?

```
const click = Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');
const mousedown = Observable.fromEvent(button, 'mousedown');
const mouseup = Observable.fromEvent(button, 'mouseup');
const mouseleave = Observable.fromEvent(button, 'mouseleave');
```

Here's the observer:

```
const observer = () => {
    console.log('click');
};
```

In other words, I'm trying to make my button work similar to native arrow buttons on input elements with type number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it:

```
  const button = document.getElementById('button');

  const click = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');
  const mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'mousedown');
  const mouseup = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'mouseup');
  const mouseleave = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'mouseleave');

  const observer = () => {
    console.log('click');
  }

  click.subscribe(observer);
  const notifier = mouseup.merge(mouseleave);
  const final = mousedown
    .switchMap(e => {
      return Rx.Observable.interval(200).takeUntil(notifier);
    })
    .subscribe(observer);
```